# Nmap script not executed

Tags: nmap

I'm sure it's something simple but I can't figure it it. I have an nmap command like the following, because I want to test the tool with my website

```
nmap -p80 --system-dns --script http-wordpress-plugins.nse legault.cc
```

The output is the following

```
Starting Nmap 7.11 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-03-24 20:42 Eastern Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for legault.cc (192.254.232.221)
Host is up (0.092s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.71 seconds
```

It seems to me that the script should run, because the port is open, Wordpress is installed correclt and the login page is at /wp-login.php

Advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you run `locate http-wordpress` what do you see?

Comment: Use `-d` to see script debug output. Add `--script-trace` to see packet data from NSE scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http-wordpress-plugins` script was renamed to [`http-wordpress-enum`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-wordpress-enum.html) in [version 6.49](https://nmap.org/changelog.html#6.49BETA1). If you still have the old script, it may not work the same with the current version of Nmap. The new version works for me with that target. You can use the `-d` option to see debugging output from the script that may be helpful.